# System files not showing in Finder Search Results

Tags: finder, macos

I have enabled showing hidden files in Finder and I can see them when viewing containing folder.  However, when I search for such files they do not show in the search results.  Specifically I was searching for .bash_profile, which I have created and edited before and I know exists in the file system, but it is not appearing in the results in Finder.  I enabled including System Files in Finder but that did not help.  What other changes do I need to do in my system to enable finding these files?

Comment: I gave up fighting it years ago - just get [EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) it's so much simpler

Comment: Welcome - it's freeware, btw, though I'd pay for it [no affiliation]  ;)

Comment: Yes, by all means they deserve it :-)